# Best of Code Review 2016 - Best Title category

Tags: discussion, fun, best-of

Please post your nominations for the [Best of Code Review 2016 - Best Title](/a/7106) category.

> *The question with the best title.*

In your nomination post, please make sure to include a link to the **revision of the question** (from the revision history) that introduced the nominated title, as well as a short explanation of what makes that post worthy of being nominated in this category, and why it should win over the others.

The following [SEDE query](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7131/best-of-code-review-2016-best-title-category) includes all question titles in 2016 along with view counts and score.

---

<sub>**Small characters at the bottom:**
Only one nomination per post. Nominated questions must have a creation date in 2016. Downvotes don't count. Santa reserves the right to award the top-voted nominee a special bounty as a token of appreciation on behalf of the Code Review community.</sub>

Comment: The "SEDE query" link, is linking back to this page...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm nominating the following question:

## [The right way to hang a man](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/131314/the-right-way-to-hang-a-man)

While the title could be considered somewhat dark, it's still a very unique and clever way of titling a question about [Hangman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangman_(game)), compared to the bland titles usually found in the [hangman](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hangman) tag. The question has also accrued over 25 votes, more than 2500 views and is currently the top question in the [hangman](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hangman) tag.

Comment: there is only 1 answer on this question

Comment: @Malachi Is the question required to have more than one answer?

Comment: no, I am just trying to make my nomination look better.  :)

Comment: vote for <s>Pedro</s> Malachi!

Answer (score 13):

One of the questions that I think drew the most attention this year due to its title is:

### [How clean is my snow?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/118538/how-clean-is-my-snow)

As evidenced by the 10,000+ views and multiple answers, the title, which accurately describes the topic of the question, must have invoked in many of us who grew up in colder climates some childhood memories of freshly fallen, pure white snow.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to Nominate my [rags-to-riches](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rags-to-riches) question

[Too Many Staff Meetings](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/144790/too-many-staff-meetings)

for the Best Title of 2016, because ...  Too many staff meetings

And because, 2400 views and 4 upvoted answers and again ...  <sub>too many meetings</sub>

Answer (score -1):

I'm going to nominate my re-titling of [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/134359/guess-the-chocolate-box)  from its original title of "[Gives correct output but slow](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/revisions/134359/1)" to "[Guess the chocolate box](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/revisions/134359/2)".

I think the new title reflects what it is the code does and contributed to pushing the question onto the HNQ list despite it only attracting a single answer.

I'd like to think that it demonstrated a better titling strategy for a [new user](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/110971/raghav-raghavendra) for any future questions, however possibly not since they haven't been seen since.